# Using AngularJS $scope within OpenCPU

Tags: javascript, angularjs, opencpu

I have an alright knowledge of angularjs but I am more of a R programmer and I have therefore being experimenting with OpenCPU js library.

One thing I can't get my head around is why I can't assign the output from a simple API request to the public OpenCPU server, rnorm(n = 2) function, to an angular $scope. What baffles me is that I can use jquery to assign the returned json via ID for example.

From what I understand it is best practice not to mix jquery into the angular controller. Am I right in thinking this?

**Working with Jquery**

```
app.controller('rCtrl', function($scope){

  req = ocpu.rpc('rnorm',{
    n : 2
  }, function(output){$('#output').text(output)});
})
```

**Not Working $scope**

```
app.controller('rCtrl', function($scope){

  req = ocpu.rpc('rnorm',{
    n : 2
  }, function(output){$scope.normalValues = output)});
})
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you are using a non-angular tool you are assigning $scope.normalValues outside of the Angular digest loop. Use a $scope.apply() to fix this:

```
app.controller('rCtrl', function($scope){

  req = ocpu.rpc('rnorm',{
    n : 2
  }, function(output){
     $scope.$apply(function(){
         $scope.normalValues = output;
     });
  )});
});
```

You can also just call $scope.$apply() right after you set your scope value but I personally like the callback syntax since it makes it easier to see why you use it.

Comment: Thanks @Bas. Exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: My pleasure. Please don't forget to upvote and mark as answer ;)

Answer (score 1):

I'm guessing it's because your function never triggers a `$digest` cycle - so you'd have to force one with `$timeout`

```
app.controller('rCtrl', function($scope, $timeout){
    req = ocpu.rpc('rnorm',{
        n : 2
    }, function(output){
        $timeout(function() { $scope.normalValues = output })
    })  
})
```

Comment: $timeout is not the right thing to use here. It works but it's actually the $scope.apply inside the $timeout that makes it happen so you can (and should) use that instead. It's more descriptive as well.

Comment: @BasSlagter -- `$apply()` is actually not what you want - it can cause issues if you try and use it mid digest - `$timeout` is the safe way to do this.

Comment: What issues are you referring to? It should not give issue unless something else in your code is terribly wrong (which can happen if you use timeout like this to much ;))

Comment: @BasSlagter -- If a `$digest` cycle is already in progress somewhere else, `$apply` will throw an error.

Comment: If a digest was already in progress this code should work without any apply or timeout ;) with $timeout you are just closing your eyes from something else going wrong in your app if a $apply gives you an error.